# how to add a <li> tag to every line automatically when exporting a HTML file in org mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode, emacs24

now i am using org-mode 8.0.2. recently i found it is really a waste of time,i should type 
lots of repetitive <li> tags when listing a heap of items. now i just want to implement a function as follows:

```
<customization-tag>
first statement;
second statement;
third statement;
</customization-tag>
```

when it is exported to a html file. it will be converted to below format automatically

```
<ul>
<li>first statement;</li>
<li>second statement;</li>
<li>third statement;</li>
</ul>
```

I found the **HTML preamble** may be helpful, but I don't know where to start.

Can some help me out?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you don't want to use a list  (See the [manual](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Plain-lists))?

Using Org 8.02 and the following:

```
- First statement;
- second statement;
- third statement;
```

And then exporting to HTML `C-c C-e C-b h H` (for temp output of body only in this case) I get:

```
<ul class="org-ul">
<li>First statement;
</li>
<li>second statement;
</li>
<li>third statement;
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of an alternate approach, but if you're willing to do it manually (i.e. not programmatically), I'd vote for a simple `^(.*)$` regex find-and-replace.  It'd also be easy to convert to a programmatic script, though again, this is a bit of a hack-workaround instead of a solution.

[EDIT] Sorry, didn't see the emacs flag at first... Try the command
`M-x replace-regexp <RET> regexp <RET> newstring <RET>`

via: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Replace.html

Comment: At present, i just want to implement automatically, anyway you have already given me a good choice. at least it will be more efficient than the way i'm using right now. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try [cua-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/CuaMode). With it, you can edit column in Emacs. See [this video](http://vimeo.com/1168225) for details.

Comment: wow It's awesome. but it is not exactly what I want. thanks anyway.